# How to scrub javascript from user-inputted HTML?

Tags: javascript, xss

How can I safely render user-inputted HTML and remove javascript? How do Gmail, Yahoo Mail and the other big players on the internet safely render email as HTML and scrub out malicious JavaScript?

Comment: This is usually done server-side.

Comment: I have found this blog post to be pretty informative: http://www.floyd.ch/?p=761. Basically, there's no way we can guarantee  security. And to the moderators that marked this question as a duplicate, YOU'RE MISTAKEN.

Answer (score 0):

USE THE function strip_tags() from php
WHEN YOU GET THE value of post or get in the  server side  you can
strip it out.